# Responsive Navbar with CSS

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive, nav

I am trying to make my navbar responsive at 500px width using media queries without using the hamburger sign. I want to make the "menu" div that houses the links to be broken into a new line directly under the one with the "company-name" when the screen is reduced to anything under 500px. Anyone out here that can help?

```css
#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #38b000;
  color: #FFFFFF
}

.company-name {
  font-size: 32px;
  flex: 1;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 20%;
  font-size: 18px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <h2 class="company-name" title="Return to Home Page"><a class="company-link" href="">URL Saver</a></h2>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="" class="nav-link" href="/">Login</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" href="/">Logout</a>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" href="/">Profile</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you remove `display: flex` from the `#nav-bar` CSS rules, doesn't that do what you want?

Comment: It moves the whole navbar from the top leaving a white space over it

Comment: Then you need to offer a little more detail on what exactly you want; do you want the menu to be always beneath the company name? Only at specific screen sizes/widths? What should happen with the rest of the space (if you don't want "white space over it")?

Comment: Okay I want the "menu" to be under the company name at 500px width, using a media query.

Comment: Remember: the only information we have about what you're trying to do, is what you've told us. Please: read the guidance on "*[ask]*", and then [edit] your question to add the details we need to address your problem. You say you've tried to change `flex-direction` to `column` and that it "*did not seem to work,*" so what went wrong? Where did it fail? Did you want the menu to be a single column, or for the links to be arranged horizontally?

Comment: when I made `flex-direction` to `column` there was no change made to the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution was just to input `flex-direction: column;` at the specific width. Then just a little CSS manipulation to make it all nice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this media in the last of you css file:

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #nav-bar {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .menu {
        max-width: 35%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not getting me the desired result

Comment: I want the menu div to drop down to the next line when at 500px

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with media queries by targeting the max-with of desired-size like shown in the example if the size of the browser goes below 1700x its gonna change its flex-direction to column and change the height to auto.

```css
* {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav-links {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    height: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: gray;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-links">Home</li>
      <li class="nav-links">About</li>
      <li class="nav-links">Services</li>
      <li class="nav-links">Email</li>
      <li class="nav-links">Something</li>
      <li class="nav-links">SignUp</li>
      <li class="nav-links">Login</li>
      <li class="nav-links">Loremips</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do as you require, though more information in the question is always useful; the code is explained in comments within the code:

```css
/* custom CSS property: */
:root {
  --flex-direction-nav: row;
}

/* simple, naive CSS reset to minimise cross-browser issues by
   specifying the box-sizing algorithm, and removing margin and
   padding from elements: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* setting the font-size of the <body> to allow other font-sizes
     to be assigned based on the em (this is my preference, feel free
     to adjust to your own preferences): */
  font-size: 16px;
}

#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  /* specifying the flex-direction to the value held in the custom CSS
     property-value: */
  flex-direction: var(--flex-direction-nav);
  /* assigning 'left over' space to be placed between the elements, not
     before, after and between: */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* balancing the padding so the menu-bar looks well-proportioned and
     'balanced': */
  padding-inline: 10px;
  background-color: #38b000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.company-name {
  /* 1em is 16px, 2em is 32px: */
  font-size: 2em;
  /* you had assigned a max-width of 20% to the .menu element; here I specified
     that the .company-name element should be four times larger than that '20%'
     element, which preserves the 20% while there is space but otherwise allows
     all elements to take the required space: */
  flex-grow: 4;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  gap: 1em;
  /* assigning 'left over' space to be placed between the elements: */
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

/* in screen media, when the max-width is 500px (or less): */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   /* we redefine the custom CSS property, which is automatically applied once it's
      changed: */
   :root {
    --flex-direction-nav: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <h2 class="company-name" title="Return to Home Page"><a class="company-link" href="">URL Saver</a></h2>
  <div class="menu">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
    <a lass="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/0c5tkrqm/).

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/).
- [CSS Custom Properties (`--*`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).

Comment: Thanks this gave me the required result